# Why is my cloth simulation doing this?

Tags: cloth-simulation

So I've just learnt about cloth simulation and I've applied it to my player's skirt as well as added a collider on the player model but this is where the issue is:

[image: Property of CraftyMaelyss do not use without permission]

I've included the settings I have for both the cloth simulation on the skirt and the collider modifier on the player's body.

When I press play, the skirt shrinks into itself but then goes back to normal and I have no idea why. I followed this tutorial for pinning and using the cloth simulator on the skirt(in case it helps at all)
https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-clothing-for-a-character-with-blender--cms-27059

Any and all helpful advice would be greatly appreciated :) Also due to this model being for an upcoming game, I cannot upload or share it, sorry :(

Comment: Maybe you should turn on self collision... but correct me if I´m wrong.

Comment: You can even see it in the screenshot you provided, it's in the cloth settings under Cloth collision. Just tick the box and try.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually better to make a cloth sim with a single surface and add a solidify modifier under the cloth sim because this way it has half the number of polygons to compute for the simulation and it keeps the thickness of the cloth constant.